# Учет оборудования. Создание параметров в клиентской части

Tags: sql-server, проектирование

Хочу сделать *электронный журнал* для ведения списка оборудования, с возможностью создания параметров в клиентской части, т.е. появилось новая позиция со своим уникальным набором характеристик, пользователь добавил оборудование, создал необходимые параметры и добавил их.

Для этих целей я сделал следующие таблицы в бд:

*Справочник параметров оборудования*

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ParametersOfEquipments (
  Id INT IDENTITY,
  TypeId INT NOT NULL,
  Name NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
  Created DATETIME NOT NULL,
  AuthorId INT NOT NULL,
  Deleted TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
  CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ParametersOfEquipments]
      PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id),
  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ParametersOfEquipments_dbo.Users_AuthorId]
      FOREIGN KEY (AuthorId) REFERENCES dbo.Users (Id)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

*Таблица оборудование*

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Equipments (
  Id INT IDENTITY,
  TypeId INT NOT NULL,
  Name NVARCHAR(MAX) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
  Model NVARCHAR(MAX) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
  AssetNumber NVARCHAR(15) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
  UnitId INT NOT NULL,
  Created DATETIME NOT NULL,
  AuthorId INT NOT NULL,
  Deleted TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
  CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Equipments]
      PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id),
  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Equipments_dbo.EquipmentTypes_TypeId]
      FOREIGN KEY (TypeId) REFERENCES dbo.EquipmentTypes (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Equipments_dbo.Units_UnitId]
      FOREIGN KEY (UnitId) REFERENCES dbo.Units (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Equipments_dbo.Users_AuthorId]
      FOREIGN KEY (AuthorId) REFERENCES dbo.Users (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

*История параметров оборудования*

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.HistoryParametersOfEquipments (
  Id INT IDENTITY,
  EquipmentId INT NOT NULL,
  ParameterId INT NOT NULL,
  Value NVARCHAR(MAX) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
  ValidFrom DATETIME NOT NULL,
  ValidTo DATETIME NOT NULL,
  Created DATETIME NOT NULL,
  AuthorId INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.HistoryParametersOfEquipments]
      PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id),
  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.HistoryParametersOfEquipments_dbo.Equipments_EquipmentId]
      FOREIGN KEY (EquipmentId) REFERENCES dbo.Equipments (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.HistoryParametersOfEquipments_dbo.ParametersOfEquipments_ParameterId]
      FOREIGN KEY (ParameterId) REFERENCES dbo.ParametersOfEquipments (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.HistoryParametersOfEquipments_dbo.Users_AuthorId]
      FOREIGN KEY (AuthorId) REFERENCES dbo.Users (Id)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

В таблице `ParametersOfEquipments` есть поле `TypeId` предполагаю создать справочник типов параметров, т.е. что то типа: `string`, `int`, `DateTime`, `bool`.

Но некоторые параметры должны быть выбраны из справочника: например параметр *Подразделение*(поле `UnitId` в `Equipments`), ну или *Состояние оборудования* должно выбираться из справочника возможных состояний и т.п.

Подскажите пожалуйста как необходимо *изменить*/*доработать* приведенную схему для реализации выбора значений *некоторых* параметров из таблиц справочников в бд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Схема, которую вы используете для гибкого задания параметров оборудования, называется *Entity-Attribute-Value* ([EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)) - *сущность-атрибут-значение*. Также известна как *объектная модель* или *вертикальная модель*.

В статье на en.wiki по приведённой ссылке крайне рекомендую к прочтению пункты:

- 4.3 The Value
- 8 Scenarios that are appropriate for EAV modeling
- 9 Working with EAV data
- 12 Alternative XML

Если вкратце, то.

Хранение значений всевозможных типов параметров, как это сделано у вас, в одном столбце типа `Value NVARCHAR(MAX)` - самый простой способ, но и самый неэффективный. Лучше сделать по столбцу на каждый тип (в этом случае можно их сделать `SPARSE`):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.HistoryParametersOfEquipments
(
    ...
    ParameterId INT NOT NULL,
    ValueString NVARCHAR(MAX) SPARSE NULL,
    ValueInt INT SPARSE NULL,
    ValueBool BIT SPARSE NULL,
    ValueDateTime DATETIME SPARSE NULL,
    ...
)
```

При больших объёмах данных разносят значения разных типов по таблицам - своя таблица для значений каждого типа параметра.

Если значения параметров могут ссылаться на справочники, то реализовать это можно, добавив в таблицу значений столбец `ValueLookupID INT`, ссылающийся на соответствующий справочник. Если справочников несколько, то либо заводят по столбцу на каждый из них, либо объединяют все нужные справочники в один, разделяя значения в общем справочнике по группам.

Также стоит рассмотреть альтернативы, такие как хранение параметров и значений в столбцах `XML` типа (к примеру, если наборы параметров для разных единиц оборудования крайне разнородны).

И последнее по списку, но не по значимости. Т.к. EAV отображается в реляционную модель не без недостатков, крайне важно не ошибиться в том, что именно EAV следует использовать для решения конкретной задачи, иначе может быть неудобно с ней работать.

Comment: на самом деле основной набор параметров будет следующим: *Подразделение, Состояние*, из опциональных я предполагаю: *Дата выпуска, Серийный номер* но возможны другие параметры например: Дата предыдущего/следующего ТО ну и.т.п.

Comment: @Bald, вряд ли я могу понять то как это будет использоваться лучше вас, поэтому могу давать только общие рекомендации. Принципиально важный момент - это будут ли пользователи _создавать_ параметры (это склоняет в пользу EAV), или скорее будет так, что параметры можно определить заранее (пусть даже их пара десятков и какие-то из них необязательны), а пользователи будут только _задавать им значения_ (это склоняет в пользу реляционной модели, т.е. вынесения параметров в столбцы).

Comment: @Bald, также замечу, что сейчас у вас `ValidFrom, ValidTo, Created, AuthorId` можно указать для каждого параметра. В реляционной модели, при вынесении параметров в столбцы, держать 4 доп. столбца для каждого будет неудобно, удобнее будет иметь `ValidFrom, ValidTo, Created, AuthorId` для всего набора параметров сразу. Если такое неприемлемо, то это склоняет в пользу EAV.  Комбинированные (EAV + relational) подходы также применяются. Иногда (если, например, по доп. параметрам не будет отчётов/запросов) достаточно иметь текстовое поле комментариев, где пользователь укажет нужные доп. сведения.

Comment: атрибуты могут изменяться по отдельности, поэтому для каждого параметра период действия, в дальнейшем я планирую использовать *параметры оборудования* для построения различных выборок: например получить список оборудования у которого то должно быть в периоде, и т.п. как поступить со значениями параметров из справочника я так и не решил, на текущий момент у меня справочники разнесены по разным таблицам

Comment: @Bald, значит видимо всё-таки EAV. Что касается справочников, то я бы наверное поступил так. Если их будет использоваться в значениях параметров не слишком много (скажем пара-тройка), то я бы создал по столбцу на справочник. Если же их десятки, то я бы объединил справочники в один.

Answer (score 1):

Добавляете еще один тип данных "enum". Создаете таблицу вида:

```
create table enums(
  Id INT NOT NULL,
  ParameterId INT NOT NULL,
  Name NVARCHAR(XX) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_enums]
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id),
  CONSTRAINT [FK_enums_parameters]
     FOREIGN KEY (ParameterId) REFERENCES dbo.ParametersOfEquipments(Id)
);
```

В `enums` ведете возможные значения для данных типов параметров. В таблице `HistoryParametersOfEquipments` в поле Value кладете ID из этой таблицы, когда конкретному оборудованию надо записать данное значение параметра. Ссылочную целостность придется контролировать триггерами. Как вариант, решаете, что в `HistoryParametersOfEquipments` разные типы параметров лежат в разных полях и тогда заводите там поле ValueEnum с которого можно сделать честный foreign на ID из enums.

Но подобная схема удобна, когда все справочники в системе лежат в одной таблице с едиными сквозными ID. Возможно с таблицами расширений для особых параметров. Если же справочники уже существуют и каждый в своей таблице со своими ID, то можно предложить в `enums` первичным ключом сделать `(id, ParameterId)` и дублировать триггерами из основных таблиц справочников ID и имена. Для каждого справочника в системе сразу создавать запись в `ParametersOfEquipments` что бы в дальнейшем все использовали именно ее.