# Хранение характеристик товаров разных категориий

Tags: sql, база-данных

Как оптимально организовать хранение характеристик товаров для разных категорий?

Мне это видится созданием отдельной таблицы характеристик для каждой категории, а в таблице категорий добавить столбец, в который будут записываться названия таблиц с характеристиками для каждой категории.

Верно ли это? Много таблиц выйдет...

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/514927/179270)

Comment: как по мне проще организовать как одну таблицу характеристик  и хранить там ВСЕ характеристики   и связывать их по id  с категорией из таблицы категорий

Comment: Присматриваюсь к EAV, спасибо @Bald.

Comment: @Broouzer King, тогда придется все характеристики хранить в тексте, а выборку по храктеристикам делать будет не очень удобно

Comment: EAV сложен для серьёзных обработок. Да и с типами не всё там так уж просто. Посмотрите заодно в сторону хранения набора характеристик в JSON - большинство СУБД имеют встроенные средства работы с этим типом, позволяющие и фильтровать, и индексировать их.

Comment: почему в тексте? кто вам мешает разбить атрибуты  по типу , хранить данные в varchar и в зависимости от типа обращаться к ним соответственно ?

 как вариант выше комментарий хранить все в jSON, но имейте ввиду что там тоже строка

Comment: еще как вариант создать сводные  таблицы значений характестик по  типу значений, хотя не очень понятно что у вас там за столь разные значения, в 90% случаев это либо строка либо число, типизация там не строгая так что числа в принципе можно хранить в строках